# batch script reading chrome extension message from stdin

Tags: batch-file, google-chrome-extension

I've a batch script being triggered by **chrome native messaging**
chrome extension is sending data to it using stdin
the whole script does run and I could parse the data I need

The issue is when data is sent from chrome using native messaging it does nothing,
(probably the script runs but can't get any data)
but when I refresh the chrome extension then I see the data logged into the `logg.txt`

I'm using this batch script

```
@echo off
setlocal
set str=
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('more') do (
   set str=%str%%%a
)
set str=%str:~9,-2%
set str=%str:\\=\%
echo %str%>>logg.txt
```

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47629019/read-all-data-from-stdin-in-a-batch-script)

I want to do it without python and pyinstaller's exe

also seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587091/chrome-extension-message-passing-to-batch-file) I couldn't understand this one.

Comment: Why are you attempting to parse the output of the `MORE` command?  

`MORE` is intended for interactive (human) use, not consumption by other programs.

Comment: Google Chrome extension native messaging sends data using stdin.
I'm not sure what can I use instead of `MORE`